# Rules to know which particle phrases modify which verb?

Tags: grammar, particles

In [this video](https://youtu.be/uO1rHcwjADA) the following sentence is analyzed

> それはある女の子が先輩のアパートで行われた飲み会に参加した日

In the video we learn that ある女の子が is the subject of 参加した, while 先輩のアパートで modifies 行われた. Put differently: the outer particle phrase modifies the outer verb, while the inner particle phrase modifies the inner verb.

I totally understand that this is the right way of looking at this sentence (given the meaning of the words, context, etc); however, **I am curious if it is logically possible for ある女の子が to be the subject of 行われた and/or for 先輩のアパートで to modify 参加した?**

Or are there rules like "the first が phrase must be the subject of the main sentence (not any relative clause found within the sentence)", or other such rules governing what can modify what (outside of pure context)?

Comment: アバパート should be アパート, no?

Comment: It is simply semantic. 女の子 can't 行われる.

Comment: 女の子が行われた is practically impossible because 女の子を行う makes no sense (in accepted meanings of the verb). 先輩のアパートで参加した is possible, but it would leave 行われた飲み会 as the target of 参加した. This would be like saying “a held party”. When “held” modifies a party, you would expect it to come with some information such as the party’s time or place. This binds 先輩のアパートで more strongly with 行われた than with 参加した.